# What does $$ do in Rstudio markdown document?

Tags: markdown, rstudio, pandoc

I accidentally typed `$$` somewhere in the markdown portion of my Rstudio markdown document and found that all downstream markdown coding had been turned off. It took me a while to trace the problem to the `$$`, which appeared in dark-red color.

My question is what does `$$` do? I have looked in markdown documentations and have not found any references to `$$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$$` is a markup for math. See the [relevant section in the pandoc manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math). Everything written between two `$$` markup will be interpreted as tex math (here is [some documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics)). Note that you can also use a single `$` sign. `$$` will produce a block element (a paragraph) while `$` will produce an inline element. Thus, `$$` is often used for equations.

Try for instance:

```
Here is an inline formula: $\frac{\alpha}{n}$ that shows...

Here is a standalone equation: $$x \approx \frac{\alpha}{n}$$
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have a math package installed, just have not used it. So in my R markdown document, the 1st `$$` was looking for a 2nd `$$` to end the block element.