# Is there a way to fix the alignment of the ordered list in RMarkdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, markdown

The placement of my ordered list appears in the middle instead of at the [top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lm0U.png). Is there any way to make it so the a) is aligned at the first line of the equation?
This is my code:

```
a) 
$\begin{aligned}
\hat{y} &= (\overline{x_1} - \overline{x_2})'S^{-1}_{pooled}x \\
&= \left(\begin{bmatrix}3\\6\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}5\\8\end{bmatrix}\right)'\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}-2&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} \\
&= -2x_1
\end{aligned}$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another set of `$` signs; one at the beginning and the other at the end.

```r
a)
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{y} &= (\overline{x_1} - \overline{x_2})'S^{-1}_{pooled}x \\
&= \left(\begin{bmatrix}3\\6\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}5\\8\end{bmatrix}\right)'\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}-2&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} \\
&= -2x_1
\end{aligned}$$
```

[image]

Quoting the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466662/what-does-do-in-rstudio-markdown-document), the difference between the 2 is:

> $$ will produce a block element (a paragraph) while $ will produce an inline element. Thus, $$ is often used for equations.